# Requesting permissions for schedule exact alarms and send notifications in Android 14

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-permissions

I want to request from the user to grant permissions for schedule exact alarms and send notifications, that disabled by default in Android 14.
I've already added in the manifest to use these permissions, but I don't know how to require the user to manually approve them.

Here are the permissions usage from the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

Those permissions are disabled by default (Android 14), and I have to ask the user for enabling them.

Comment: add code as well so other developer can understand your issue